# Android beta APK distribution issues

Tags: android, google-play

I'm attending the Hacker News meetup tomorrow in DC, and I'll be showing off my Android application. I'd like to have a QR code for people to scan to try my app out.

Should I be concerned about giving my unreleased APK out to strangers? I've heard of vendors having their beta APKs uploaded to market under someone else's account. I plan on putting it on the Android Market eventually for $1. I uploaded an initial version to Market to hold the package name, but what stops someone from re-signing it with their information? Is this even possible?

I was thinking of signing it with a key that expires in one month to prevent people from running beta versions forever. Does this work?

Comment: maybe you just implement some sort of "self-destruct" mechanism, i.e. your your beta app just exists if the date is more than x months from now?

Comment: what does the qr code contain? the link to your app on the market?

Comment: Gryphius, do you mean a check on the date, perhaps? I could even make a server-side check using the version of the app. That seems like it'd be pretty elegant.

Comment: @Sbossb: good question. It'd be a link to the APK hosted on my web server for use by users who have enabled installation of APKs from unknown sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it seems like you have a couple options.

1) Upload your app to the market and sign it with your long term key.That way users who install the app at the conference will be able to receive updates. The only drawback to this is that you have to release it as a paid app. Once an app it released as free you can not change it!

2) Sign the app with a key that expires soon. From [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html). "If you plan to support upgrades for a single application, you should ensure that your key has a validity period that exceeds the expected lifespan of that application. A validity period of 25 years or more is recommended. When your key's validity period expires, users will no longer be able to seamlessly upgrade to new versions of your application." It seems that users will still be able to run your app but not upgrade when the key expires.

3) Have your app enforce the "beta" by checking the system time and if it is past a certain point, do not allow access to your app.